# SlimFramework php 404 issue with custom multilang groups

Tags: php, routes, slim

I tried to make my own multilang application using slim framework. I generated routes groups for all the languages which contains the all standard applications routes like this :

```
$this->app->group($base_folder, function () use ( $base_folder ) {

    include 'includes.php';

    $availableLangs = explode(",", USE_MULTILINGUAGES);
    if(strlen($availableLangs['0']) > 0){
        foreach($availableLangs as $availableLang) {

            $this->app->group('/'.$availableLang, function () {
                include 'includes.php';
            });

        }
    }
});
```

My file include.php contains my standard routes like this :

```
//Redirect to Home
$this->app->map('/', function () {
    echo '/'.'<br/>';
    $this->app->redirect('home');
})->via('GET');

//Homepage
$this->app->map('/home', function () {
    $data = new Admin\GetController( 'home' );
    $data->send("Home/home.template.html");
})->via('GET');

//Others
require 'Routes/Login.php';
require 'Routes/Logout.php';
require 'Routes/Users.php';
```

The routes generated are good, when I display it :

```
project/
project/en
project/fr
project/home
project/en/home
project/fr/home
```

etc...

But when I try it in browser, just the standard ones are working ( project/ and project/home ). The custom with /fr or /en go to `$this->app->notFound`

- Why isn't it working ?
- Is there a better way to do it ... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was rewriting the Slim variable ['PATH_INFO'] when extracting the lang from url. It is why it was not working. So it works fine now but I am still interested to know if there is a better way to add multilang to a slim app.

usefull ressources

- http://nesbot.com/2012/6/26/multilingual-site-using-slim
- https://fiberonofiber.wordpress.com/2014/02/13/slim-php-multi-language-urls/
- https://github.com/SimoTod/slim-multilanguage